# Open page in Facebook,Twitter and Google Plus app from other app - Android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-intent, google-plus

I'm working on an application where I need to integrate the social functionality of the different social networks: Facebook, Twitter, Google+.

For now, in Facebook and Twitter i'm recognized if the user has a native application and if he does, I'm opening it and show him my fan page.

For Twitter I use the next code:

```
try {

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=[user_name]"));
    startActivity(intent);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
             Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/[user_name]"))); 
    }
```

And for Facebook the next code:

```
try{

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/" + PROFILE_FACEBOOK_APP_ID));
startActivity(intent);

}catch(Exception e){

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/UserNamePage")));
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing for Google+. I saw that I can browse to my fan page with the next Url `https://plus.google.com/MY_PAGE_ID/`, but it keep asking me if I want to open it with Google+ application or with the browser, and I want that he will open it with the application automatically, without asking the user.

Is there a simple way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.plus",
"com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.UrlGatewayActivity");
intent.putExtra("customAppUri", "FAN_PAGE_ID");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Ovidiu Latcu For package name you can use PackageManager to get the right package name.

Comment: they can change the extra name.. whatever. this is not gonna hold. it will also crash if G+ not installed.

Comment: @Ovidiu Latcu Check before if G+ application is installed, or just put try catch to avoid the crash and handle the exception in your on way. This method is sufficient for me, feel free to suggest a better way.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is quite safe, because we do not need to specify the component, just the google+ app package name:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/[Google+ID]/"));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus"); // don't open the browser, make sure it opens in Google+ app
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unknown if google plus needs some other information in the Intent but as general Android solution you can explicitly set the target. You will need the package name of google+.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29

For example:

```
Intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus"); //Don't know the exact package name
```