# QR Code that opens Google Plus App

Tags: android, ios, qr-code, google-plus

I'm trying to link my organization's Google + page through a scanable QR code. When they scan the code it brings them to the Google + page in their mobile browser. **Is there a way to get the phone to open up the Google + app to our page?** I know you can do it with Facebook *(fb://page/)*, Twitter *(twitter://user?screen_name=),* and Foursquare *(foursquare://venues/VENUE_ID)*

Answer (score 1):

You propably should start Activity with approciate Intent.ACTION_VIEW. If user has Google+ installed then should start application.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/yourlink")));
```

Also refer to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867989/open-google-plus-page-via-intent-in-android) or this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327799/open-page-in-facebook-twitter-and-google-plus-app-from-other-app-android)

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading somewhere that the Google+ URL scheme for iOS was `Mgc://` but for some reason, I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

However, Google does have an extensive guide on how to share to Google+ linked below.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/#share_on_google

Answer (score 0):

Typing "gplus://" into Safari's address bar in iOS 7 does indeed launch the Google+ app on this iPhone 4S I'm typing on, I can assure that. Documentation, however, is a whole other issue...